# react date picker some dates can not be selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-datepicker

I am using a react date picker, like:

```
<DatePicker
 selected={selectedDate}
 onChange={handleDateChange}
 minDate={new Date()}
 className="form-control"
 />
```

this is what it looks like, in this photo I hover with my mouse over number 1, and you can see the backound changing. I can also select 1st of november:

[image]

like this:

[image]

the problem is some dates when I hover with my mouse over them, it doesnt recognize it, and I am not able to select some dates at all.
in the above example I can only select the dates from 26th of november to 2nd of December.
I am not sure how to fix this or why the styles or something else is being overwrittem and I cant find the reson for it.
Also I have tried to rn the datepicker in a seprate app and it work correctly there, but in this project the styke is being overwritten.

why is this happening and how can I fix that?

Comment: Add z-index 9999 to your date popup through css, I think some of background uses absolute element and get on "top" of your date picker, on empty page your date picker shoud work fine

Comment: @bob yes thats it, there are some elements on back ground and this is what causing it.
thank you for pointing it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

debug your handleDateChange. try to console.log the its parameters.

and double check that if you set State (the selectedDate) correctly.